# How to link up to a browser in QTP?

Tags: qtp

I am new to qtp and this is a sample script in which I am facing a few errors like "URL might be wrong".

```
Browser ("Google").Navigate ( "http://www.google.com")
Browser ("Google"). Page ("Google").Sync
Browser ("Google"). Page("Google").  WebEdit("q:"). Set (" tarun lalwani")
Browser ("Google") .Page  ("Google"). WebButton ("Google Search").Click
Browser ("Google") .Page (" tarun lalwani - Google").link ("knowledgeInbox").Click
Browser ("Google").Page ("knowledgeInbox").Sync
Browser ("Google") .close
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what sort of errors you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you've taken the example from Tarun's website. A couple of questions/pointers:

1. Is this *all* the code from your sample script?
2. Do you have the object repository that I expect comes with this example script?
3. Are all those random spaces present in your actual QTP code?
4. What *exact* error message are you getting? I think "URL might be wrong" is probably not what you're really getting...

Answer (score 1):

1. Check whether you stored objects in the object repository
2. Try the below mentioned code

   ```
   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   IE.Navigate "http://www.google.co.in"
   IE.Visible = True
   IE.Document.All.Item("q").Value = "serach"
   IE.Document.All.Item("f").submit()
   ```
3. There shoudl be no spaces in the code. For example your script is

   ```
   Browser ("Google") .Page  ("Google"). WebButton ("Google Search").Click
   ```

   it should be

   ```
   Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebButton("Google Search").Click
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the browser:

```
browser("IE").Page("website name").etc.......
```

Or store it in a variable:

```
set a=browser("IE").page("name of ur site etc")
a.webedit("name of text field").set "pavan"
a.webbutton("search").click
```

You can also create a local repository
before running the script.

Answer (score 1):

```
SystemUtil.Run "iexplore","URL of the application"
With Browser("A").Page("B")
    .WebEdit("Logical Name of the Text Field").Set"SearchKeyText"
    .WebButton("Text label of the Button").Click
End With
```